# Test and conditionally update a long using Interlocked

Tags: c#, thread-safety, interlocked

Is there a neat way to do this using the `Interlocked` class? Or should I just use `lock { }`?

My specific use case is that I have multiple threads that compute a `long` value, and compare it to a shared "Maximum" value, replacing the shared value only if the local value is larger.

Comment: Sorry you're out of luck here, use a `lock`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yss0xc74.aspx) method. I haven't tried, but something like this seems *logical* to me:

```
long localMax = Interlocked.Read(ref max);
while (value > localMax) {
  Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref max, value, localMax);
  localMax = Interlocked.Read(ref max);
}
```

As usual, stress test your code to try to catch concurrency issues.

Comment: `CompareExchange` only checks for equality. You can't act on "greater than" comparisons etc.

Comment: Those reads of the `max` field aren't guaranteed to be thread-safe.

Comment: That's OK, because the `CompareExchange` will "synch" with the current value of `max`.

Comment: Ohhh, but since it's a `long`, the read might not be atomic on 32 bit machines.... I'll update.

Comment: True, but those reads of `max` could mean that `localMax` contains stale or torn reads. It's possible -- although unlikely -- that you could end up looping unnecessarily and/or infinitely because of this.

Comment: stale reads wouldn't be a problem, but torn reads would! That's why I've updated

Comment: You don't appear to update value or localMax within the while body, therefore if it executes once it will infinite loop

Comment: @Rob: `localMax` is updated as the last statement in the loop. How come you didn't spot that?

Comment: Heh: Cos I read the `);` of Compare Exchange as the closing brace of the while loop. Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

So long as the value of your shared field only ever increases then you could do something like this with a combination of [`Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.read.aspx) and [`CompareExchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yss0xc74.aspx).

```
long sharedVal = Interlocked.Read(ref _sharedField);
while (localVal > sharedVal)
{
    long temp = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _sharedField, localVal, sharedVal);
    sharedVal = (temp == sharedVal) ? localVal : temp;
}
```

However, I would go for a plain `lock` in this situation: using `Interlocked` like this is less readable than a `lock` block and has the potential for much poorer performance too.

Comment: Doesn't this risk an infinite loop? Supposed initially `sharedField` is 1 and `localVal` is 2. After the `Interlocked.Read`, another thread nips in and sets `sharedField` to 3. The Exchange will then return 3, so `sharedVal` will never change.

Comment: Also, I accept that a lock solution is certainly more readable, but why would an Interlocked solution be poorer performance?

Comment: @Rob: Yep, that was a mistake! I've already fixed just before your comment appeared.

Comment: @Rob: As for performance: this could potentially do tens/hundreds/thousands/millions etc iterations, with `CompareExchange` "failing" every time because the shared field is continually updated by other threads with a new value that's still lower than this thread's `localVal`. A plain `lock` will only need to wait-compare-exchange once (even though that wait could be a relatively long time compared to a small number of `Interlocked` calls).

Comment: Good point. Just out of curiosity, I might run some empirical tests. In my use case, each thread might try to update the shared field every 200ms or so. Presumably, a couple of instructions in the while loop will be so fast by comparison as to rarely if ever be pre-empted more than once.

Comment: @Rob: That's true, but if that's the case then an uncontended `lock` will also be lightning-fast. It'll be interesting to see the results of your benchmarks; please post them if you get a chance.